# Immediate passing php variable between pages

Tags: javascript, php

I need to send php from other php page back to index at the same time. 
I use $_SESSION , but it shows result only after I refresh page.
In index I'm getting values from inputs sending them through button onClick action myAjax().

```
function myAjax() {
var range = document.getElementById('range').value;
var port = document.getElementById('port').value;
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: 'nova2.php',
   data:{action:'call_this',range:range,port:port},
   success:function(html) {
    // alert(html);
   }
});
}
```

to nova2.php, where I do query on database and getting array which I want to send back to index.php

```
while ($row = $query2->fetch_assoc()) {
    $port_list[] = $row['port_name'];

}

$_SESSION["var_name"] = $port_list;
mysqli_close($con);
```

I put almost same ajax script under this php function (of course without session), but it wasn't working. I didn't recieve any value in index.php

```
type: "POST",
url: 'index.php',
data:{action:'action',port_list:port_list},
```

Is there any other way?
Thank you

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear to me. What exactly do you want? Do you simply want the array returned to the index file?

Comment: yes..I want to get array to index

Comment: So echo it out? `success:function(html)` means `html` contains whatever the php code echos

Comment: when I use type:POST , url:index.php, ... in nova2.php as I wrote ..and try to echo it in index..I am not getting any value

Comment: Now it looks.. fill inputs in index.php -> button onClick function myAjax -> post values into nova2.php, do query with these values, get array ($port_list) ... Now I would like to POST/SEND $port_list back to index.php. So basically send array between php and another php or between php and js in index.php.

Comment: and in index.php array needs to go js script: **var input = <?php echo json_encode($my_var); ?>;** where my_var = $port_list.

Answer (score 0):

If you need SESSION value on same page where from you have requested AJAX to nova2.php.

in `nova2.php`

```
while ($row = $query2->fetch_assoc()) {
    $port_list[] = $row['port_name'];

}

$_SESSION["var_name"] = $port_list;
mysqli_close($con);
echo json_encode(array('port_list'=>$port_list));
```

In your AJAX function

```
function myAjax() {
var range = document.getElementById('range').value;
var port = document.getElementById('port').value;
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: 'nova2.php',
   dataType: 'json',
   async: false,
   data:{action:'call_this',range:range,port:port},
   success:function(data) {
     port=data.port_list;
   }
});
}
```

I hope it should be work.
Thanks

Comment: No I dont need to use session. This is also giving me results only after page refresh. But thanks ;)